# mysql subquery extremely slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, subquery

I show a sales query which involved multiple tracking tables. (showing only some data)

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT(cam.c_prefix, LPAD(v.id_sale,5,'0')) Code,
    ve.estate_name last_state,
    v.date_instalation, 
    va.date_state date_modification  
FROM sale v 
INNER JOIN headquarters_detail sd ON v.id_headquarters_detail = sd.id_headquarters_detail 
INNER JOIN headquarters se ON sd.id_headquarters = se.id_headquarters 
INNER JOIN campaign cam ON sd.id_campaign = cam.id_campaign 
INNER JOIN sale_activity va ON va.id_sale = v.id_sale 
INNER JOIN state_detail vec ON vec.id_state_detail = va.id_state_detail
INNER JOIN sale_state ve ON ve.iid_sale_state = vec.iid_sale_state
WHERE  v.flag = 1 
AND     EXISTS( SELECT  '1' 
                            FROM sale_history
                            WHERE   id_sale = v.id_sale 
                            AND flag = 1
                            LIMIT 1)  
AND v.id_headquarters_detail = 2
```

this query takes **0.650s**. I want to add in different columns, subquery, I return the last state of the sale distributed by stages. Something like:

```
id_sale | ... | last_state_of_stage_1 | last_state_of_stage_2 | last_state_of_stage_3
01      | ... | new_sale              | distributed_sale      | canceled_sale
02      | ... | new_sale              | distributed_sale      | invoiced_sale
...
```

The states and stages of every sale are stored in a history:

```
sale_history
------------
id_history  int  -- primary key
id_sale int
id_state_detail int -- contains the states id's and logic
observation tinytext
date_history    datetime
id_user int
id_profile  int
...
```

indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX indx_id_sale USING BTREE ON sale_history (id_sale);
CREATE INDEX indx_id_state_detail USING BTREE ON sale_history (id_state_detail);
```

Each history has an average of 25 records for sale. To get the status of the sale, I think a subquery (and for each of the stages):

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT(cam.c_prefix, LPAD(v.id_sale,5,'0')) Code,
    ve.estate_name last_state,
    v.date_instalation, 
    va.date_state date_modification,  

IFNULL((SELECT state_name
            FROM sale_history veh 
            INNER JOIN state_detail vec ON  vec.id_state_detail = veh.id_state_detail 
            INNER JOIN sale_state ve ON ve.iid_sale_state= vec.iid_sale_state
            WHERE veh.id_sale = v.id_sale
            AND vec.iid_sale_stage = 5
            AND veh.flag = 1  
            ORDER BY veh.id_history DESC
            LIMIT 1
),'x') last_state_of_stage_1

FROM sale v 
INNER JOIN headquarters_detail sd ON v.id_headquarters_detail = sd.id_headquarters_detail 
INNER JOIN headquarters se ON sd.id_headquarters = se.id_headquarters 
INNER JOIN campaign cam ON sd.id_campaign = cam.id_campaign 
INNER JOIN sale_activity va ON va.id_sale = v.id_sale 
INNER JOIN state_detail vec ON vec.id_state_detail = va.id_state_detail
INNER JOIN sale_state ve ON ve.iid_sale_state = vec.iid_sale_state
WHERE  v.flag = 1 
AND     EXISTS( SELECT  '1' 
                            FROM sale_history
                            WHERE   id_sale = v.id_sale 
                            AND flag = 1
                            LIMIT 1)  
AND v.id_headquarters_detail = 2
```

but this subquery **115.985s** delay! I wonder because it takes so long?

**EDIT 30-09-13**

By fancyPants's comments, I made ​​some changes which has greatly improved the speed of the query:

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT(cam.c_prefix, LPAD(v.id_sale,5,'0')) Code,
    ve.estate_name last_state,
    v.date_instalation, 
    va.date_state date_modification,
    IFNULL(ve5.state_name,'x') last_state_of_stage_1
FROM sale v 
INNER JOIN headquarters_detail sd ON v.id_headquarters_detail = sd.id_headquarters_detail 
INNER JOIN headquarters se ON sd.id_headquarters = se.id_headquarters 
INNER JOIN campaign cam ON sd.id_campaign = cam.id_campaign 
INNER JOIN sale_activity va ON va.id_sale = v.id_sale 
INNER JOIN state_detail vec ON vec.id_state_detail = va.id_state_detail
INNER JOIN sale_state ve ON ve.iid_sale_state = vec.iid_sale_state
LEFT JOIN sale_history veh5 ON veh5.id_sale = v.id_sale AND veh5.flag = 1 AND veh5.id_history = (SELECT MAX(sh.id_history) 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    FROM sale_history sh 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    INNER JOIN state_detail vecx ON vecx.id_state_detail = sh.id_state_detail
                                                                                                                                                                                                    INNER JOIN sale_state vex ON vex.iid_sale_state= vecx.iid_sale_state
                                                                                                                                                                                                    WHERE sh.id_sale = v.id_sale AND sh.id_sale = veh5.id_sale
                                                                                                                                                                                                    AND sh.flag = 1
                                                                                                                                                                                                    AND vecx.iid_sale_stage = 5
                                                                                                                                                                                                    )
LEFT JOIN state_detail vec5 ON vec5.id_state_detail = veh5.id_state_detail
LEFT JOIN sale_state ve5 ON ve5.iid_sale_state = vec5.iid_sale_state
WHERE  v.flag = 1 
AND     EXISTS( SELECT  '1' 
                            FROM sale_history
                            WHERE   id_sale = v.id_sale 
                            AND flag = 1
                            LIMIT 1)  
AND v.id_headquarters_detail = 2 
AND EXISTS(SELECT '1'
                FROM sale_activity veh
                INNER JOIN state_detail vec ON  vec.id_state_detail = veh.id_state_detail 
                INNER JOIN sale_state ve    ON ve.iid_sale_state= vec.iid_sale_state
                WHERE id_sale = v.id_sale
                AND iid_sale_stage = 4
                LIMIT 1)
```

Now take **0.609s** to display data, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try if this query works better:

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT(cam.c_prefix, LPAD(v.id_sale,5,'0')) Code,
    ve.estate_name last_state,
    v.date_instalation, 
    va.date_state date_modification,  
    COALESCE(state_name, 'x') last_state_of_stage_1
FROM sale v 
INNER JOIN headquarters_detail sd ON v.id_headquarters_detail = sd.id_headquarters_detail 
INNER JOIN headquarters se ON sd.id_headquarters = se.id_headquarters 
INNER JOIN campaign cam ON sd.id_campaign = cam.id_campaign 
INNER JOIN sale_activity va ON va.id_sale = v.id_sale 
INNER JOIN state_detail vec ON vec.id_state_detail = va.id_state_detail
INNER JOIN sale_state ve ON ve.iid_sale_state = vec.iid_sale_state
INNER JOIN sale_history veh ON veh.id_sale = v.id_sale AND vec.iid_sale_stage = 5 AND veh.flag = 1 
WHERE  v.flag = 1 
AND v.id_headquarters_detail = 2
AND veh.id_history = (SELECT MAX(id_history) FROM sale_history sh WHERE sh.id_sale = veh.id_sale);
```

If it doesn't (assuming it produces correct results), execute it again with `EXPLAIN` in front of it and post the results, please.

Answer (score 1):

The inner query is run seperatly for every row of your table over and over again, rising exponentially your query time (gets worse with more records). This is why subqueries are to be treated with care in real world applications.

I suggest you try a different approach to this query (there are many cases where some complex combination of JOINs can replace a subquery).